# ExtJS - multil language with i18n texts

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I was searching info in the itnernet , and I find some information how to change languages in ExtJS. it is [on the dev.sencha.com](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/locale/multi-lang.html?lang=ukr&charset=UTF-8)

As I see, they use  **locale/ext-lang-{0}.js files.**

Ok That's great! but I need to **change my own texts too**. For example I have  Ext.MessageBox.alert and I want to get text from properti files.

Is there any way to use i18n files too? **Using  langauge parameter of URL (?lang=en, ?lang=fr) use text-en.properties or text-fr.propertes.**

I need a good tutorial link, how to create multi language ExtJS page.

I see **Ext.ux.Localizer** add on. [link](https://github.com/devotis/Ext.ux.Localizer) but I dont understand how to use it. how to change language :(

thank you.

Comment: I just bought the book 'Mastering ExtJS 4'. They talk about it. I didn't read yet all. Once I got through it, I will resume it here.

Comment: The solution in 'Mastering ExtJS 4' works, but is really basic. It also requires to use special code like `title: translation.my_title`what is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend looking at the Ux.locale.Manager plugin which works well (https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/Ux.locale.Manager).

I have written an article on how to use it which might be of use: https://web.archive.org/web/20141103155453/http://www.swarmonline.com:80/2013/02/localising-sencha-touch-and-ext-js-applications-with-ux-locale-manager/

Comment: using this, you can't create, for instance, Ext js alert with your text.

Comment: You can call the 'get' method to grab translations inline - Ux.locale.Manager.get('my.text.translation') I often make an alias to it on app launch to a very short global method for easiness.

Comment: @Alex I've updated it to point to a way back machine version, hope you get it working.